# How to .catch a Promise.reject

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a helper function for using `fetch` with CouchDB which ends as:

```
...
return fetch(...)
  .then(resp => resp.ok ? resp.json() : Promise.reject(resp))
  .then(json => json.error ? Promise.reject(json) : json)
```

and when I use it elsewhere, I was under the impression that I could `.catch` those explicit rejections:

```
  above_function(its_options)
    .then(do_something)
    .catch(err => do_something_with_the_json_error_rejection_or_resp_not_ok_rejection_or_the_above(err))
```

but alas, I can't seem to be able to get a hold of the rejections.
The specific error I'm after is a HTTP 401 response.

What gives?

(Please note that there are implicit ES6 `return`'s in the `.then`s)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```js
    function test() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return reject('rejected')
      })
    }

    test().then(function() {
      //here when you resolve
    })
    .catch(function(rej) {
      //here when you reject the promise
      console.log(rej);
    });
```

Comment: So I guess it makes my question a xy question, I hate when that happens.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure every call to a `then()` returns a value.

For e.g.

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.co.in';
var options = {};
var resolves = Promise.resolve();

resolves.then(() => {
  console.log('Resolved first promise');
  var fetchPromise = fetch(url, options);
  fetchPromise.then(() => {
    console.log('Completed fetch');
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
```

Notice the `console` shows an uncaught exception. However, if you returned the inner promise (or any other value, which ends up turning into a promise via `resolve`), you end up flattening the promise so exception bubble up.

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.co.in';
var options = {};
var resolves = Promise.resolve();

resolves.then(() => {
  console.log('Resolved first promise');
  var fetchPromise = fetch(url, options);
  return fetchPromise.then(() => {
    console.log('Completed fetch');
  });
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('Error', error);
});
```

Notice the exception bubbles up to the outer promise. Hope this clears up things a little bit.

Comment: Please note the "Please note" at the end of the question. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but that's the case when you use expressions that do no require curly braces in your arrow functions. I was not 100% sure that was the case everywhere in your code. :)

Answer (score 5):

Why not wrap it in a `try / catch` block

```js
// define a failing promise
const test = ()=> new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('rejected'));

// using an immediately executing function to call an async block
(async ()=> {
  try {
    await test(); // => this will throw an error
  } catch (er) {
    console.log(er); // 'rejected'
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Promise rejections fall to the second param of the `then` function.

```
function test() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return reject('rejected')
  })
}

test().then(function() {
  //here when you resolve
}, function(rej) {
  //here when you reject the promise
    console.log(rej)
})
```

Comment: The catch() method returns a Promise and deals with rejected cases only. It behaves the same as calling Promise.prototype.then(undefined, onRejected) (in fact, calling obj.catch(onRejected) internally calls obj.then(undefined, onRejected)).

Comment: I've read a lot of documents claiming everyone should avoid that style since it can't catch the "left" side, and use the `.catch` instead.

Comment: @ivo, put some example together.I haven't been able to do that and have it work. Maybe I screw somewhere

Comment: @yBrodsky posted.