# How can handle Promise Reject when use findById Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In Reposity, I use this following code to handle not match `_id` when findById:

`getById: function (id) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            if (!id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
                // Yes, it's a valid ObjectId, proceed with`findById`call.
                console.log('Not match id');
                reject('Not found');
                return;
            }
            propertyModel.findById(id).exec(function (err, item) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(item);
            });
        });
    },`

And in Controller:

```
getListProperty: function (req, res, next) {
    let query = req.query;
    try {
        propertyRepo.getList(query).then(item => {
            return res.status(200).json(item);
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json(err);
    }

}
```

And I can't handle error when not found `_id`. How can I handle it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to .catch a Promise.reject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005954/how-to-catch-a-promise-reject)

Comment: Use `.catch` on the Promise, not `try` / `catch`

Comment: Thank @CertainPerformance. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to declare .catch to handle error on promise

```
getById: function (id) {
            return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                if (!id.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
                    // Yes, it's a valid ObjectId, proceed withfindByIdcall.
                    console.log('Not match id');
                    reject('Not found');
                    return;
                }
                propertyModel.findById(id).exec(function (err, item) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(item);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    reject(error)
                })
            });
        },
```